# MongoDB Login system & sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session, mongodb

I am using MongoDB on my PHP website to keep hold of my registered users, and their login. So far, so good.

When I log in, I am using the following (simplified):

```
$login = $collection->findOne(array("mail" => $mailIn, "pass" => $passIn));
if($login) {
    $_SESSION["gatekeeper"] = $login['_id'];
}
```

and when I register, the following:

```
$collection->insert($obj);
mkdir("$appDirectory/users/" . $obj["_id"]);
$_SESSION["gatekeeper"] = $obj["_id"];
```

The whole system is working good, but there is something that is bugging me: take a look at the JSON derived from this in the session manager:

```
"{\"gatekeeper\":{\"$id\":\"505f1cd25c73959504000000\"}}" (redis)
array(1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "505f1cd25c73959504000000" } (php var dump - gatekeeper)
```

as you can see, it's storing it as an associative array $id->id.

of course it would be much better to have simply gatekeepeer->id.

How can I change this easily? I honestly find it confusing because of this "$id" that makes my PHP confused a bit, and confuses me as well.

---

Basically the annoyance is when I have to retrieve the gatekeeper:

```
$gatekeeper = $_SESSION["gatekeeper"];

$userID = $gatekeeper['$id']; //WILL work
$userID = $gatekeeper; //WON'T WORK
```

it would be much simpler (and better) to just have:

```
$userID = $_SESSION["gateID"];
$userName = $_SESSION["gateName"];
....
```

instead of:

```
$gatekeeper = $_SESSION["gatekeeper"];

$userID = $gatekeeper['$id'];
$userName = $gatekeeper['name'];
```

since the $_SESSION always refer to the same session there is no need to have an array inside the array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> _id contains MongoId instance

so you need to convert it into string before assign into session variable

As below

```
$_SESSION["gatekeeper"] = (string) $obj["_id"]
```

Comment: great! I knew it would be something really simple to do, just couldn't figure out how.